# fbx model import, polygon surface not OK

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, import, faces

[image]I imported this .FBX file.
.FBX file contains a rigged model, no textures.
In 3D view the model looks like it has a grayscale checkerboard on it, every face/polygon has a separate gray tone applied.
When I add a subdivision modifier it looks normal.
Whats going on here?

Comment: Hi and welcome :) It is not clear what exactly your problem is without seeing images of the object. Please [edit] your question and add more information. Thanks

Comment: Possibly bad custom normals? Try "Clear Custom Split Normals Data" under "Geometry Data" in the mesh tab in the properties editor.